# Lines after setInterval executing before setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

In the code snippet below, I have a `setInterval` followed by my `console.log`. As you can see, `endNode` is initialized to `null` which should be updated inside `setInterval` and the `console.log` should print the updated node. At least, that is what I am trying to achieve.

However, in my console, I get `null` as the output. It seems like playing with some more code that the lines (`console.log` in this case) are executed before `setInterval` is executed. Or perhaps it may be a scoping issue.

Is there a way to fix this so that I am able to print the updated value of `endNode`?

```js
let endNode = null;

let BFStimer = setInterval(function() {
  if (Q.size() > 0) {
    let u = Q.dequeue();
    if (u.end) {
      $(".r" + u.x + "c" + u.y).addClass("explored");
      setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(BFStimer);
      });
      endNode = u;
      return u;
    }
    let N = u.neighbor;
    for (let i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
      if (N[i].isWall) {
        continue;
      }
      if (N[i].status === "undiscovered") {
        N[i].status = "discovered";
        $(".r" + N[i].x + "c" + N[i].y).addClass("discovered");
        N[i].parent = u;
        N[i].distance = u.distance + 1;
        Q.enqueue(N[i]);
      }
    }
    $(".r" + u.x + "c" + u.y).addClass("explored");
  }
}, 5);

let currentPathNode = endNode;
console.log(currentPathNode);
```

Comment: `endNode` won't be set for the first time until the interval has run after the 5ms delay. Excecution continues on past the interval as normal while the delay is active. This is expected behaviour. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: setInterval is not blocking the site (which is actually good and desired behavior). you should learn about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: There's a lot of job to do within 5 milliseconds.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what `setInterval` even does.   Your code does this:  set node to null, setup an interval to run every 5m **and after 5ms for the first time**, output node.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior, it's not a bug and thus there's no fix. When you call `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, `nextTick`, and so on you are not immediately executing the code, but you are scheduling a task that will be executed when the current micro/macro task is finished.

You can just move the code to an external function and call it both inside and outside the `setInterval`:

```
function myFunc() {
  if (Q.size() > 0) {
    let u = Q.dequeue();
    if (u.end) {
      $(".r" + u.x + "c" + u.y).addClass("explored");
      setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(BFStimer);
      });
      endNode = u;
      return u;
    }
    let N = u.neighbor;
    for (let i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
      if (N[i].isWall) {
        continue;
      }
      if (N[i].status === "undiscovered") {
        N[i].status = "discovered";
        $(".r" + N[i].x + "c" + N[i].y).addClass("discovered");
        N[i].parent = u;
        N[i].distance = u.distance + 1;
        Q.enqueue(N[i]);
      }
    }
    $(".r" + u.x + "c" + u.y).addClass("explored");
  }

}

myFunc();
let BFStimer = setInterval(function() {
  myFunc();
}, 5);
```

Comment: The above snippet will produce an error because the variable `BFStimer` is evaluated before the definition, but I hope you understood the logic of this :)